# Matching multi token entities in spacy

Tags: spacy

I am trying to use Spacy's rule based matching as follows:

```
nlp_ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True, validate=True)
nlp_ruler.add_patterns(match_rules)
ents = nlp_ruler(doc).ents
```

Thing is, the entities are matched but the tokens are labeled separately. So, if two tokens form a single street name, both words (tokens) will be labeled as "street_name", but there seem to be no indication in the entity objects themselves that they are indeed connected.

Unlike rule-based entity matching, if NER is used, seems that there are indicators such as IOB and BILUO schemes. But these are not available for the rule-base matching. So how do I merge the entities? (merge_entities will not work here either for some reason ...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may need to double check your patterns to see whether they are constructed correctly, here is a working example for your reference:

```
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True, validate=True)
ruler.add_patterns([
    {"label": "WHEN", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "the"}, {"LOWER": "other"}, {"LOWER": "day"}]},
    {"label": "WHAT", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "camouflage"}, {"LOWER": "trousers"}]},
])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)


doc = nlp("I went to buy some camouflage trousers the other day but I couldn’t find any.")
ents = ruler(doc).ents
ents = [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents]
ents
```

Output:

```
[('camouflage trousers', 'WHAT'), ('the other day', 'WHEN')]
```

Comment: Thing is, if you annotate using phrase matcher in a previous stage, your ent's will get overridden. Sometimes this is not desirable...

Comment: By design phrase matcher is a boolean mechanism and should override a statistical approach, therefore it is advised to use phrase matcher when you are confident about its output. However, this is not stated in your question, therefore it might be worthwhile to ask a new question about ner being overwritten by phrase matcher. Also, please let me know if the answer works for your question.

Comment: As you might guess the answer is complex. I guess I did do something stupid putting the same name as my phrase matcher and the results under the same name. Yet it would be still nice if there were such option to deep copy the doc object.